# Long thread of discussion between 2 persons and multiple edits awaits approval

Tags: discussion

I am trying to help someone with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74477353/how-to-display-multiple-table-column-values-in-a-single-dropdown-on-a-razor-page/74480995?noredirect=1#comment131593189_74480995) question. It was a bit unclear at first but I managed to help a little bit by asking a lot of questions in the comments and by making multiple edits. [My last edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/33247234) though awaits moderation for quite some time and they cannot see my last update. As you can see from the question and comments the OP is a beginner and a lot of back and forth discussion is unavoidable in this kind of scenario.

My question is: what is the SO policy for this scenario, when an answer kind of becomes like a chat or a mail thread between two persons and no one else contributes?

Comment: Unclear questions should be closed not "answered" with guesses. Your edit to the question is not good, don't edit a post to write your reply to a user there. Also don't write "edit" to every edited part.

Comment: You've edited [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/33247234). Did you mean to edit your answer instead?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the answer, not the question.

Comment: Edits on your own content do not need approval. If you think you edited your own answer but are waiting for edit approval, you did in fact edit the wrong content.

Comment: Your mistake aside, long discussions should take place in a chatroom (there is usually an option to move to chat after a certain number of comments, at least on questions). Some consideration should be given to flagging the question for closure as unclear or needing debugging details.

Answer (score 1):

It was my mistake. At some point I edited the question, not the answer.
It's ok to downvote me for this. I would have done the same thing.

Comment: On SO votes are done on posts, not on users.

Comment: Really? Then how do you explain that after I posted  this question ( which I recognized it was my mistake, it happens), someone went on and downvoted a question that I asked 8 months ago, to which I provided my own answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71400547/in-a-service-mesh-architecture-the-call-from-service-a-to-service-b-must-happen

Comment: See [What is the meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269349/1595451)

Comment: `It's ok to downvote me for this.` - no, is not ok, nor is ok to downvote a post for being edited (even if it's edited a lot). As others have said, content should be upvoted/downvoted, not users/actions. With emphasis on **should**.